# ¿Cómo valido si una IP es correcta en Bash?

Tags: regex, ubuntu, bash, debian

He estado trabajando en un Script sh que ejecuto desde un CRONTAB. Dicho script tal cual como lo tengo hasta el momento funciona y se encarga de verificar que ip tiene el equipo y efectúa la actualización en los servidores DNS de CDMON.

Adicionalmente, me gustaría complementar el script corriendo una función que haga una verificación de la ip que tiene el equipo: si la misma no es una ip pública, el bucle se repita hasta que exista una ip asignada y que la misma sea una ip publica. De esta manera seria un poco mas automatizado.

He encontrado por la web la siguiente function

```
function valid_ip()
{
local  ip=$1
local  stat=1

if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
    OIFS=$IFS
    IFS='.'
    ip=($ip)
    IFS=$OIFS
    [[ ${ip[0]} -le 255 && ${ip[1]} -le 255 \
        && ${ip[2]} -le 255 && ${ip[3]} -le 255 ]]
    stat=$?
fi
return $stat
}
```

Asi como esta esta function funciona de manera perfecta pero a mi me gustaría adaptar dicha function para que si por alguna razón no existe dirección ip o la dirección ip es una ip privada es decir 192.168.1.(cualquier otro numero) entonces se ejecute el comando `sudo dhclient -r` y luego `sudo dhclient`

¿Será eso posible de hacer y cómo lograrlo? Dejo aca el Script que estoy utilizando de momento. Así como está funciona así el equipo una ip publica o privada y es lo que quiero evitar.

```
#!/bin/bash
USUARIO=USUARIO
PASSMD5=CLAVE_EN_MD5
HOST=HOST
EMAIL=CORREO
echo "EMPEZANDO SCRIPT"
echo "."
echo "."
IP_DNS_ONLINE=$(host $HOST dinamic1.cdmon.net | grep -m1 $HOST | awk {'print $4'})
IP_ACTUAL=`wget -q -O - http://icanhazip.com/`
if [ "$IP_ACTUAL" ]; then
    if [ "$IP_DNS_ONLINE" != "$IP_ACTUAL" ]; then
        CHANGE_IP="https://dinamico.cdmon.org/onlineService.php?enctype=MD5&n=$USUARIO&p=$PASSMD5"
        RESULTADO=`wget $CHANGE_IP -o /dev/null -O /dev/stdout --no-check-certificate`
        echo "$(date)_____cambio de IP en CDMON.com"

        echo "Resultado devuelto: $RESULTADO"

        ANTIGUO="En Servidor = $IP_DNS_ONLINE  (antiguo)\n"
        ACTUAL="Mi Ip       = $IP_ACTUAL  (actualizado)\n"
        echo " $ANTIGUO $ACTUAL"

        MENSAJEA="Se ha actualizado la Ip del Dominio Asociado.\n"
        MENSAJEB=$MENSAJEA"Se han actualizado los servidores DNS dinamicos de CDMON.\n"
        MENSAJEC=$MENSAJEB"El resultado devuelto ha sido el siguiente:\n"
        #Finalmente envia un email con los resultados
        echo -e $MENSAJEC $ANTIGUO $ACTUAL | mail $EMAIL -s "Cambio de IP en WEBSERVERJE por cdmon.sh"
        echo "Se ha enviado un correo \n"

        else

        echo "   $(date)_____Coinciden las IPs\n   En cdmon     =$IP_DNS_ONLINE\n   Ip Local     =$IP_ACTUAL\n   No se hara nada"

    fi
fi
########################### Fin del script
```

Comment: sería bueno que empezaras indicando qué quieres hacer, con ejemplos de entrada y salida. De lo contrario, nos obligas a repasar todo el código y sacar conclusiones nosotros, por lo que podríamos perdernos cosas.

Comment: Ese script efectua una actualizacion en los servidores DNS de CDMON pero para que eso ocurra es necesario que exista una ip de caracter publica asignada al sistema, si la ip es una ip publica entonces mi script hara una asignacion a los DNS de CDMON de dicha ip. Por eso busco hacer un bucle que se rompa si y solo si la ip es una ip publica y mientras sea una ip privada el bucle se mantenga ejecutando  `sudo dhclient -r` y luego `sudo dhclient` no se como hacerlo

Comment: Edita por favor la pregunta. Creo que mucho de lo que comentas no es necesario para que te respondan, deberías proporcionar un [mcve]

Comment: Agradezco tu interés, pero considero que asi como esta formulada mi pregunta es bastante clara en lo que tengo y en lo que me gustaría hacer, no me he extendido en mi formulación..! creo prudente que el script lo deje tal cual porque si otra persona requiere usarlo lo haga de forma libre, y si se llega a actualizar de forma que haga lo que necesito entonces este conocimiento quede al acceso publico..! el ejemplo que he colocado es 100% verificable y considero que la información que he suministrado es ampliamente necesaria para que me pueda responder algún usuario que sepa como hacerlo.

Comment: de todas maneras he agregado mas informacion a la formulacion de mi pregunta, por favor si consideras que algo esta mal planteado, o esta de mas sabria mucho agradecer a tu mayor experiencia en el uso del sitio a que me colabores en formular de mejor manera mi interrogante.

Comment: Tras leer con calma tu problema, este se reduce a cómo validar si una IP es del tipo 192.168.1.X o no. El resto puede ser interesante, pero no es importante para la pregunta. Te honra querer compartir tus conocimientos, claro está! Pero preguntas tan largas suele ser costosas de seguir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para validar una IP me gusta más [lo que planteó William Pursell en 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13784147/1983854):

```
if echo "$ip" | { IFS=. read a b c d e;
    test "$a" -ge 0 && test "$a" -le 255 &&
    test "$b" -ge 0 && test "$b" -le 255 &&
    test "$c" -ge 0 && test "$c" -le 255 &&
    test "$d" -ge 0 && test "$d" -le 255 &&
    test -z "$e"; }; then echo is valid; fi
```

En tu caso, lo que quieres es que si la IP es del tipo `198.168.1.X`, lance `sudo dhclient -r` y luego `sudo dhclient`. Fácil.

Pasa primero la validación que ya tienes. Después, cuando ya sabes que la IP es correcta (y que por tanto la X de 192.168.1.X no será mayor que 255), puedes decir algo tan simple como:

```
if echo "$ip" | { IFS=. read a b c d e;
    test "$a" -eq 192 &&
    test "$b" -eq 168 &&
    test "$c" -eq 1 }; then { echo "es local"; sudo blabla}; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar lo siguiente

```
echo 199.166.20.111 | perl -e '$_=<>; exit 1 unless m/^(?!\.)(?:\.?(?:2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|1?\d?\d)\b){4}$/ && !m/^(?:127\.0\.0\.1|10\.|172\.1[6-9]\.|172\.2[0-9]\.|172\.3[0-1]\.|192\.168\.)/'
```

Tendrás el resultado en el estado de salida (`$?`) de la ejecución de dicho comando:

- 1 si no es una IP o es privada
- 0 si es una IP pública

Por ejemplo, lo podrías utilizar de la siguiente manera:

```
#!/bin/bash

ip=199.166.20.111
echo $ip | perl -e '$_=<>; exit 1 unless \
  m/^(?!\.)(?:\.?(?:2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|1?\d?\d)\b){4}$/ && \
 !m/^(?:127\.0\.0\.1|10\.|172\.1[6-9]\.|172\.2[0-9]\.|172\.3[0-1]\.|192\.168\.)/'

if [[ $? == 1 ]]; then
    echo $ip no es una IP o es privada
else
    echo $ip es una IP pública
fi

ip=172.17.19.254
echo $ip | perl -e '$_=<>; exit 1 unless \
  m/^(?!\.)(?:\.?(?:2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|1?\d?\d)\b){4}$/ && \
 !m/^(?:127\.0\.0\.1|10\.|172\.1[6-9]\.|172\.2[0-9]\.|172\.3[0-1]\.|192\.168\.)/'

if [[ $? == 1 ]]; then
    echo $ip no es una IP o es privada
else
    echo $ip es una IP pública
fi
```

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://ideone.com/TvtV4N).